# there is a easy way to visualize and modify a txt file?

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct

i'm having a little big trouble in c. in particular im not able to save and modify a .txt file on an easy and efficient way.
the fact is: from a file.txt, i have to save all the words on a struct, and after that i will have to do some operations on this, like modify a specific word, a bubble sort, ecc ecc.

Im having problem on how to correctly save all the words in the struct, in the most generic possible way, even if a word from a line of the file is missing.
i mean:

1 line: word1 word2

2 line: word3

3 line: word4 word5

So even if a word is missing, i need to be able to save all this words, leaving something like a missing space in the struct.

the code that im posting is, at the moment, the best i can make with my hands, because i dont have any more ideas about what i should do.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX (10)     //<- is 10 because the max numbers of letters in any single word is less than 10

struct word{
    char word1[MAX+1];  //<- here im defying a struct with 2 char. this struct will contain the words coming out from the file.
    char word2[MAX+1];  //<- max+1 because i have ti give 1 space for the " " or the "/n" case.
};

struct word *file_read(FILE *fp, int *count){
    
    int dim = 2;        //<- the int dim is the dimensione
    char buf[1024];     //<- a simple buffer
    struct word *w;
    int conv = 0;       //<- another counter that i will use in sscanf
    int i;
    
    if(!(w = calloc(dim , sizeof(*w)))){
        free(w);
    }
    
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf),fp)!= NULL){
        conv = sscanf(buf, "%s %s", w->word1, w->word2);

        if(conv >= 1){                  //if conv doesnt increase, just no print
            printf("\n%s ", w[*count].word1);
        }
        if(conv == 2){                  //the same operation
            printf("%s", w[*count].word2);
        }
        i++;


        if(*count>= dim){
            dim *= 2;
            struct word* temp = realloc(w, sizeof(*w)*dim);
            if(temp != NULL){
                w = temp;
            }   else{
                    free(w);
                    return NULL;
                }
        (*count)++;
        }

    }
    return w;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  //<- the file will be passed by argv[1] argument
    
    FILE *fp;       //<- im defying the FILE type
    fp= fopen(argv[1], "r");    //<- im opening the file passed from argv[1], in reading mode
    
    if(fp == 0){            //<- if file is not loaded, the programm have to stop.
        printf("FILE IS NOT LOADED");
        return 1;
    }
    
    struct word *w;     //<- im creating a struct pointer called w
    int count= 0;

    if(!(w = file_read(fp, &count))){   //<- going to do the reading subroutine
        return 0;
    }

    //AFTER THE READING, I SHOULD BE ABLE TO SAVE ALL THE WORDS IN THE STRUCT
    //AND I SHOUL BE ABLE TO DO SOME OPERATIONS, LIKE VISUALIZE IT DIFFERENT WAYS
    //DO BUBBLE SORT, QSORT, MODIFY THE WORDS IN THE STRUCT, ECC...

}
```

so, please, how can i make it works???? thank you everybody.

i hope i've been clear :)

Comment: Add `int conv` to the `word` structure so that you can store the number of conversions in the structure: `w->conv = sscanf(buf, "%s%s", w->word1, w->word2);`

Comment: In which way does your program fail? Please [edit] your question and add some example input, the actual result, and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

user3386109's suggestion of adding *`int conv` to the `word` structure* is good. Still there are errors:

1. `(*count)++` is out of place, so that it's never reached. Move it to the place of the pointless `i++`.
2. In order to not store every line's words in the first structure, change all `w->` to `w[*count].`.